# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot recognize input near 'CHAR' ',' 'T2' in function specification

Tags: sql-server, hive, pyspark

I have a 4 lines of SQL queries, where I have the following substring query:

```
SUBSTRING(T2.xxx,1,10) <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T2.xxx, 111),1,10
```

I am using PySpark to create a HIVE table and push the data with the help of the query. There is no issue with the code as it is working for other SQL type queries. This is an instance where I am facing issues. Below is the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot recognize input near 'CHAR' ',' 'T2' in function specification
```

I have tried many online suggestions, but none of them work. I came across below link from the Cloudera website

```
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html
```

It says that:

> Spark SQL does not respect size limit for the varchar type.

I am not sure if I have quoted the relevant statement here. Can anybody help me understand what I am going through here and how can I rectify the error?

Comment: If possible can you paste complete error stack ?

Comment: I have already pasted the exact part of th error. Rest part is just info